# Excel Indirect Function with Row reference

Tags: excel, row

I'm trying to do two linked dropdown Boxes.
Dropdown Box A should do the Article List, dropdown B should be the articles that are on another sheet.

Two linked Dropdown Lists
[image]

If I make this for one row it works fine with this Formulas:

CELL I5    `=ARTIKEL`

CELL I6    `=INDIREKT($I$5)`

As soon as I try to to pull the formulas down on the worksheet the second dropdown list will always link to $I$5 (My Article Dropdown List `=ARTICLE`).
I couldn't find a way so that it automaticaly would reference to the actual Row.
I found the ROW() Function but I can't integrate it into the INDIRECT Function, it looks so simple.

Please can anyone help?

Comment: what's in $I$5? What result do you get and what result do you want. Please rephrase question to clarify.

Comment: $I$5 Is the reference to the first Dropdown locatet in that cell, it should be something $I$ROW() but that doesn't work. I always want to reference to the column on the left in that actual row.

Comment: If you want relative references, then don't use absolute. Try `=INDIREKT($I5)` See [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-DFEC08CD-AE65-4F56-839E-5F0D8D0BACA9) for more info

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly with `"$I$ROW()"`

The formula for linked cell reference look something like this:

```
=INDIRECT("$I"&ROW()) - if you want to lock Column I when you drag your formula
```

or relative formula

```
=INDIRECT("I"&ROW()) - if you want to switch Column when you drag your formula
```